# Is there a way to have ["Kari","can","keep","her","car."] generate the output "Kari" "can" "keep" "her" "car"

Tags: python-3.x

How can make the input

`["Kari","can","keep","her","car."]` generate an output

```
"Kari" "can" "keep" "her" "car"
```

in python

Comment: `' '.join(map(lambda s: f'"{s}"', ["Kari","can","keep","her","car."]))`?

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: again, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822 about asking homework questions. Ask a new question, show the code you've written, show the error messages, explain what the problem is. Questions like "fill in the blanks for me" are not the kind of questions Stack Overflow answers. Please show your effort and explain what exactly is not working for you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be a homework question and a simple google search would reveal how to do this.

Comment: The answer is already provided below. Good to close. I updated it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Want to simply join them by space? `join()` them by space (`' '`):

```
' '.join(yourlist)
>>> 'Kari can keep her car.'
```

If you want to keep quotes; use them while joining:

```
'"'+'" "'.join(yourlist)+'"'
>>> '"Kari" "can" "keep" "her" "car."'
```